# Sonarqube plugin development, project settings order

Tags: sonarqube

I have a plugin I have created with some project specific settings:

```
@Property(
        key = MyPlugin.SEV1,
        name = "SEVERITY 1",
        description = "Severity 1",
        defaultValue = "Blocker",
        global = false,
        project = true),
@Property(
        key = MyPlugin.SEV2,
        name = "SEVERITY 2",
        description = "Severity 2",
        defaultValue = "Critical",
        global = false,
        project = true),

....
....

@Property(
        key = MyPlugin.SEV10,
        name = "SEVERITY 10",
        description = "Severity 10",
        defaultValue = "Info",
        global = false,
        project = true),
```

These show in the web interface in the order:

SEVERITY 1

SEVERITY 10

SEVERITY 2

Is there any way to re-order/force the order the settings are shown as rather than alphabetical? I noticed some of the standard settings pages seem to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Already answered on the dev google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/PropertyDefinition/sonarqube/HwF0uQIbBfU/K8YVdZTUIAAJ

Answer (score 0):

From [SonarQube mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/PropertyDefinition/sonarqube/HwF0uQIbBfU/K8YVdZTUIAAJ) (30/07/2015)

> [Julien Henry](https://stackexchange.com/users/255011): You can use programmatic way to declare properties using *org.sonar.api.config.PropertyDefinition*. This API provides an "index" attribute that allows to tune ordering.
>
> See Javadoc for an example:
> https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/config/PropertyDefinition.java